# Finding a File Using Static Recursion

Tags: java, string, file, recursion, static

I am trying to find a file ("Vodoo.txt") on my D:\ drive using static recursion in JAVA. I was wondering if you might be able to help me find out what I am doing wrong.

My goal is to search through all of my folders until I find "Vodoo.txt" and print out the path to that file.

> My Code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class FindFile
{
  public static String searchForFile(File currentFolder, String filename)
  {
    File root = currentFolder;
    File[] list = root.listFiles();

    if(list != null)
    {
      for(File f : list)
      {
        if(f.isDirectory())
        {

          File path = f.getAbsoluteFile();
          if(f.getName().equals(filename))
          {
            System.out.println(f.getAbsoluteFile());
          }
          //System.out.println(f.getAbsoluteFile());
          return searchForFile(path, filename);
        }
      }
    }

    return "WRONG DIRECTORY";
  }


    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        FindFile ff = new FindFile();
        File currentFolder = new File("D:\\2016-2017\\Fall2016");
        String fileName = "Vodoo.txt";
        System.out.println("Search for Vodoo.txt under " + currentFolder);
        System.out.println("------------------------------------");
        ff.searchForFile(currentFolder, fileName);
    }
}
```

> Output:

Search for Vodoo.txt under D:\2016-2017\Fall2016

> My actual file location:

D:\2016-2017\Fall2016\201_CSCE_Programming\Assignment 5\RecursivelyFindFile\Vodoo.txt

Answer (score 0):

In your method you only have a check for directory.  if it is not a directory you do nothing.

should be more like

```
    if(f.isDirectory())
    {
      File path = f.getAbsoluteFile();
      return searchForFile(path, filename);
    }

    if(f.getName().equals(filename))
    {
        System.out.println("found " + f.getAbsoluteFile());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

More elegant way is to use SimpleFileVisitor from JDK:

(from JavaSE tutorial)

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.FileSystems;
import java.nio.file.FileVisitResult;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.PathMatcher;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.SimpleFileVisitor;
import java.nio.file.attribute.BasicFileAttributes;

public class FindProgram {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Path startingDir = Paths.get("D:\\");
        String pattern = "Voodoo.txt";
        Finder finder = new Finder(pattern);
        Files.walkFileTree(startingDir, finder);
        finder.done();
    }

    public static class Finder extends SimpleFileVisitor<Path> {

        private final PathMatcher matcher;
        private int numMatches = 0;

        Finder(String pattern) {
            matcher = FileSystems.getDefault().getPathMatcher("glob:" + pattern);
        }

        void find(Path file) {
            Path name = file.getFileName();
            if (name != null && matcher.matches(name)) {
                numMatches++;
                System.out.println(file);
            }
        }

        void done() {
            System.out.println("Matched: " + numMatches);
        }

        @Override
        public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path file, BasicFileAttributes attrs) {
            find(file);
            return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
        }

        @Override
        public FileVisitResult preVisitDirectory(Path dir, BasicFileAttributes attrs) {
            find(dir);
            return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
        }

        @Override
        public FileVisitResult visitFileFailed(Path file, IOException exc) {
            System.err.println(exc);
            return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
        }
    }
}
```

This program simply walks through every direction under user specified direction:

```
Path startingDir = Paths.get("D:\\");
```

It's looking for file that apply to specified `glob` pattern:

```
String pattern = "Voodoo.txt";
```

Every visited file name is checked by following method and the path to file is printed:

```
void find(Path file) {
    Path name = file.getFileName();
    if (name != null && matcher.matches(name)) {
        numMatches++;
        System.out.println(file);
    }
}
```

Before program finish number of files found is printed thanks to this method:

```
void done() {
    System.out.println("Matched: " + numMatches);
}
```

More on glob patterns you can find in Java docs, [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/fileOps.html#glob).

Comment: But I guess that the OP has homework which requires him to use recursion.  nice solution though

Comment: BUT it does not answer his question - so who knows maybe the OP will accept it as the correct answer.